# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.Ec2 after installing and configuring the files

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

Hi everyone i am getting this error now is more than  7 hours but i still have know luck "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server".
I followed the instructions and examples on the internet but i still get the same error.here is my how my file path "etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin"

```
      <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
         # Apache 2.4
        <RequireAny>
           #Require ip 127.0.0.1
           #Require ip ::1
           Require ip 52.28.232.215 
       </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.2
    # Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from All
      Allow from All
     # Allow from 127.0.0.1
      #Allow from ::1
       Allow from 52.28.232.215 
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>

   <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
     <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
      # Require ip 127.0.0.1
      Require ip 52.28.232.215
      # Require ip ::1
    </RequireAny>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.2
    # Order Allow,Deny
    #Deny from All
    #Allow from 127.0.0.1
    # Allow from ::1
    Allow from 52.28.232.215

    Allow from All

   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Any hint in the webserver error log?

Comment: hey i just got the answer now but i have a little problem i've createdth @Isaac Bennetch virtualHost and run the permission commands but i keep on getting this error     "file_put_contents(/var/www/html/kidio/mergeogle/laravel/storage/framework/sessions/2a70352d4c64b8245c86102bf448010a67b19798): failed to open stream: Permission denied" i clear my cache but still

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get that error? That's not related to phpMyAdmin for sure.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch am actually trying to setup laravel 5

Comment: Ah, okay. I was thrown off because you mentioned phpMyAdmin in the subject and the section of the Apache configuration dealt with phpMyAdmin. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this issue

added

```
 Required all granted
```

on the first

```
 # Apache 2.4
```

I was not aware that my apache is 2.4+
Thanks

Comment: its Require all granted