# 403 Forbidden access of phpmyadmin at AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-403

My /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyadmin.conf has the following configurations

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>

       Require ip xx.xx.xx.xxx
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow

    #Deny from All
     Allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip xx.xx.xx.xxx
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     #Deny from All
     Allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

When I access at my page EC2 instance as
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/phpmyadmin, I have `You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.` error.
I made sure this ip address `xx.xx.xx.xxx is my EC2's Elastic IP address`.
phpMyadmin.conf has correct xx.xx.xx.xxx to allow.
I tried to follow the similar links of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904701/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server-ec2-after-install) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324837/installing-phpmyadmin-onto-amazon-ec2-instance).
But still have the error. What could be wrong with my error?
My EC2 instance has AWS linux OS installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this configuration is related to **PhpMyadmin**. In order to load this configuration into Apache Web Server, Make sure Apache is loading all the configuration files from `conf.d` by looking into `httpd.conf` if you are using apache [Not Apache2] and apache2.conf [for Apache2].

Inside /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, you will find the following line, which includes those files:

```
# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/
```

[[Refference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11687212/2466407)

You might have checked it still, it is one of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. Follow this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html to do all owner and group changes. Did all as you did above, but it's getting that error. Finally after restarting httpd, I become able to connect.